# Why glm does not translate vertex

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm trying to translate vertex with matrix transformation using glm.

But it looks, that i'm doing something wrong. 
I tried to change side of v*m and m*v but I have same result. Res has same values as `to` after multiplication;

```cpp
void transform(V3 &to, PTransformation t)
{
  float v1 = to.x();
  float v2 = to.y();
  float v3 = to.z();

  glm::vec4 v = glm::vec4(v1, v2, v3, 1.0f);
  glm::vec3 valuesToTranslate(t.translateX, t.translateY, t.translateZ);
  glm::mat4 m = glm::translate(valuesToTranslate);
  glm::vec4 res = v * m;

  to.e[0] = res.x;
  to.e[1] = res.y;
  to.e[2] = res.z;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just add the three coordinates of `t` to the coordinates of `to`?

Comment: Usually with OpenGL, the multiplication order is m * v, not v * m

Comment: @Rabbid76 I want to add scale multiplication and rotate multiplication also. This was just an example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe your input data is not valid?
Can you show the input data

Comment: this should be a comment, and not the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this with GLM 0.9.9 and GCC 7.4.0 and it works after switching the multiplication order of `v` and `m`.

```
glm::vec4 v = glm::vec4(0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 1.0f);
glm::vec3 valuesToTranslate(8.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glm::mat4 m = glm::translate(valuesToTranslate);
glm::vec4 res = m * v;

// expected output: vec(8.0, 4.0, 0.0, 1.0)

std::cout << glm::to_string(res) << std::endl;
```

If you are still not getting the expected results in your own code I would suggest checking the input values, and failing that, checking there are no known issues with your version of GLM.

Comment: Bizarre that you would unaccept this and then accept a less detailed answer posted several days later.